# how to handle Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function when adding the model dialog in the .cshtml in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

i want to add [this dialog popup](https://jsfiddle.net/rwk1Ljcy/5/) in my MVC based project.when i add this to my code it shows the following errors when i inspect ---> console (browser console)

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function  

(anonymous function)    

jQuery.event.dispatch   @   jquery-1.11.1.js:4641

elemData.handle @   jquery-1.11.1.js:4309
```

will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Did you include the jQueryUi files?

Comment: yes i have included

Comment: Check in browser dev tools network that they are loading, that they load after jQuery.js and that you haven't included jQuery.js more than once in page

Comment: i have included JQuery.js only once and it is loading just after the jquery-ui.css....same errors are occuring

Comment: And your code loads after both? Something is wrong either in the loading order or path or you have a custom version of jQueryUI that doesn't include dialog. Post a link to live page that throws this error

Comment: Show us the output html (without the content, only scripts references, please specify which the script which calls `$(...).dialog`. Do you have a public URL of your project?

Comment: @WaqasAdil make sure that you have added  jquery-ui.js as well

Comment: make sure that you are calling the `dialog` method after loading the jQuery ui library.